# nightwatch.js cannot run chrome in headless mode

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js, google-chrome-headless

I cannot get it to run without it opening a visible browser window.
I tried both with **"headless"** and **"--headless"** arguments

Note: I am NOT using Selenium.

Acording to this page headless mode is supported in MacOSX since version 60. I'm running version 61

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Here's my configuration:

`"chrome" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : ["--headless"],
          "binary": "google-chrome"
        }
      }
    },`

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same issue earlier and the solution was to add the following args as I don't want a sandbox neither need the gpu.

*"args" : ["headless", "no-sandbox", "disable-gpu"]*

```
"chrome" : {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "acceptSslCerts": true,
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "chromeOptions" : {
      "args" : ["headless", "no-sandbox", "disable-gpu"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that exact code when I have some time but I vaguely remember trying several combinations of these same arguments and none of the combinations worked for me at the time

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux please try this, it works perfectly for me :

```
            "desiredCapabilities": {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "javascriptEnabled": true,
            "acceptSslCerts": true,
            "chromeOptions": {
                "args": [
                    "headless", "disable-gpu"
                 ],
                 "binary": "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
              }
        }
```

If you are on Mac, replace your binary path, eg `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

Comment: I tried with the binary paths such as */Applications/Google Chrome.app* and */Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome*.  Same thing. It can run the browser fine but it always opens a visible window, which is not what I expect

Comment: Please make sure the path is correct and also remember the backslash in `/Google\ Chrome` .

Comment: How can I be sure I have the correct binary path? Adding the \ did not help. Are you really testing it in MacOSX? Do you have a working nightwatch.json for MacOSX that you can share so I can try it?

Comment: yes, i am using it now. You can check by copy and paste the path in terminal then if chrome open => the path is good.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **--disable-gpu**

As the url you provided mentions :

> --disable-gpu \                # Temporarily needed for now.

which means you need it to use headless mode at the moment, it may not required in future version.

Comment: I had actually tried with that argument before, and just tried it again both with and without the dashes. At least in my machine it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem with headless mode recently. The elements can not be found. Then I debug and found all the failed cases using SSL certification URL. Then I added one option acceptInsecureCerts, it works at last. Just FYI.

nightwatch.json:

```
...
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "acceptSslCerts": true,
          "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
          "chromeOptions" : {
            "args": [
              "headless",
              "no-sandbox",
              "disable-gpu",
              "ignore-certificate-errors"
            ],
            "binary" : "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
          }
        },
```